# QT Creator , use gradle instead of ant give error

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am using QT Creator for Andorid apps. I have build my app with ant . That is ok . But If I check *Use Gradle instead of Ant* in Tools>Options>Android. That give me error like :

C:\Qt\5.7\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project ArizaMobil (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.0))
When executing step "Build Android APK"

How to correct this bug. I want to use gradle not ANT